# Started seeing these bugs in patio door slide

Tags: insect

Started seeing these in my patio door frame, any idea what these are? Location: NJ

[image: 1]

Comment: Was this today, early Feb, in the middle of the snowpocolypse of 2022?

Comment: @FreeMan I started seeing them back in December. Are these mosquitos?

Comment: Look like fruit flies to me, but that's just a SWAG. [Bug identification](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bug-identification) has officially been declared ON-topic over at [outdoors.se]. If you don't get a response here, they may be able to help.

Comment: Well with the rest of the country having snow my area has been warm and those look like mosquitoes, possibly a bit early unless they had a warm place to grow.